# What happened to Channels in project Loom?

Tags: java, project-loom, java-21

In [State of Loom: part 2](https://cr.openjdk.org/%7Erpressler/loom/loom/sol1_part2.html#channels), there's a discussion about channels, and that Doug Lea had started working on a synchronous counterpart to `Flow`, called a `Carrier`.

That was back in May 2020, and Loom is now released. I can find no further mention of Carriers or channels or any similar mechanism anywhere. Does anyone know what happened to it? Did it get released and I just can't find it?! Is it still planned for some future Java version? Was it abandoned because `LinkedTransferQueue` was deemed sufficient?

Comment: I suppose, Structured Concurrency has a higher priority at the moment.

Comment: "Loom is now released" - Technically, that's wrong. Loom isn't released, it's an OpenJDK project that's still going on. Virtual threads are finalized.